# How to hide a rewrited URL in web browser

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, hide

I used Apache's mod_rewrite to redirect HTTP request to another server. I want to keep original URL in client's browser. Now it displayed rewrited URL in client's browser. The configuration as below in Httpd.conf file. Thank you advance.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tpiaccs/
RewriteRule /tpiaccs/uat/(.*) http:///tpiaccs/uat/$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, by default it rewrites using external redirection (an implicit [R] flag) unless you specify otherwise.

This might do what you're after:

```
RewriteRule /tpiaccs/uat/(.*) http:///tpiaccs/uat/$1 [P,NC,L]
```

The P should make it internally proxy the request rather than doing an external redirect.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html for details on the flags that can be used with URL rewriting.